# FloatingActionButton black box

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm using this https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton library for FloatingActionButtons in my project.

On some smaller devices, for example the Acer Liquid Z4 (Android version 4.2.2, screen 480x800) or the Genymotion Galaxy S2 image (Android version 4.1.1, screen 480x800) the FABs have a black box around them:

[image]

I tried to narrow this down, removed any special stuff from my theme making it look like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

and also put the buttons in the most simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="de.immowelt.android.immobiliensuche.ui.FabTestActivity">


    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but the box remains. On the other hand I tried to recreate the effect with a new project but couldn't do it.

The box disappears when using the `mini` size version or disabling the shadow.

Any ideas on what my problem is?

PS: I tried cleaning the project ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `FloatingActionButton` class makes use of a drawable called `shadow.9.png` for the shadow. I also had a `shadow.9.png` in my drawables and the library class obviously picked up the wrong one (mine). 
Renaming my drawable solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was using that library but then decided to make my own, set this as the background to an imageButton or something. I used a textview because all I needed was a +. It looks pretty good in my app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

            <padding android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00262626" />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

            <padding android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#0D262626" />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

            <padding android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#26262626" />

        </shape>

    </item>


    <!-- Background -->

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

            <solid android:color="#448AFF"/>

        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: That's nice but I need the additional methods of that library.

Comment: Fair enough. I did this also because the shadow isn't quite right on most of the action button libraries. What features are you using?

Comment: Attaching the buttons to s ScrollView for example. I know this can all be down with own code but that's something I really don't want to do.